# I'm solving Set Matrix zeros and getting this error in LEETCODE in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

CODE:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void setZeroes(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
       
    // Write your code here.
    
    int m = matrix.size();
    int n = matrix[0].size();
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
        
    for(int i = 0 ; i<n ;i++){
        if(matrix[0][i]==0)
            x=0;
    }
    for(     int j = 0 ; j<m ; j++){
        if(matrix[j][0]==0)
            y=0;
    }
    for(    int  i = 1;i<m;i++){
        for(    int j=1;j<n ;j++){
            if(matrix[i][j]==0){
                matrix[i][0]=0;
                matrix[0][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    for(    int i = 1;i<m;i++){
        for(    int j=1;j<n ;j++){
        if(matrix[0][i]==0 || matrix[j][0]==0)
        {
            
                matrix[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    if(x==0){
        for(    int  i = 0 ; i<n ;i++){
            matrix[0][i]=0;
        // continue;
    }
    }
    if(y==0){
        for(    int j = 0 ;j<m ;j++){
            matrix[j][0]=0;
        // continue;
        }
    }
}

    
};
```

ERROR :

Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h) 0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here  SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib

Comment: In one place you switch place of `i` and `j`. Which will be bad if `m != n`.

Comment: Here's a twist -- you know that the program has a bug, so it's your job to find the bug and fix the issue.  I guess LeetCode doesn't tell you that to be a programmer, if you write code, you need to know how to debug your own code that you write.   Also, not debugging your own code is reason to downvote a question.  I know debugging may not seem "fun", but that's the responsibility of every programmer, beginner or advanced.

Comment: The big issue is that the volunteers had to make the effort in doing the job you should have done.  You don't have to fix the problem, but at the very least, identify where the problem is.  That requires you to debug the code and see where the program deviates from the plan you had in mind.  Too many posters post a program that doesn't work, have no input into why it doesn't work, and wait for StackOverflow to debug their code while they sit back and relax, waiting for an answer.  It shouldn't work that way.

Comment: Too bad there are still some that choose to reward bad questions with answers, instead of cleaning them up. What's baffling is how many of them don't seem to be the type that desperately wants karma.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is the above comment directed at me? I can't say I understand your point.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what exactly might've led you to believe that I had you -- or anyone else in particular -- in mind, @john.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well I answered this question, and you seem to be agreeing with Paul that it's a bad question. If I've misunderstood then I apologise.

Comment: No, I definitely agree with Paul, that this is a bad question, @john. Do you agree?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No I don't agree it's a bad question.

Comment: Well, then we'll agree to disagree.

Comment: `x` and `y` should be bool

Answer (score 1):

This loop doesn't work

```
for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (matrix[0][i] == 0 || matrix[j][0] == 0)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

See how `i` is begin used in the first subscript and in the second. Same goes for `j`. Unless `m == n` this is going to result in out of bounds accesses in `matrix`.